# How to open Nebular Accordion by default with Ngfor

Tags: angular, html, angular7, nebular

I am using latest Nebular version with Angular 7, facing an issue while using nebular accordion.
Issue: By default active accordion should expanded not all, I have tried to use expanded = true but with this all accordion expanded which is not the use case.

```
<nb-accordion>
    <nb-accordion-item *ngFor="let list of lists" expanded =true >
        <nb-accordion-item-header>
            {{list.name}}
        </nb-accordion-item-header>
        <nb-accordion-item-body >
            <ul >
                <li *ngFor="let item of list.category" [value]="item.id" 
                [ngClass]="{'active': item.id == categoryId}">
                    <div class="col-9">{{item.name}}</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nb-accordion-item-body>
    </nb-accordion-item>
</nb-accordion>
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you need to expdand a particular element, you can move the expanded flag inside of your `lists` array, something like this:

```
  lists = [
    {
      name: 'Test',
      expanded: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2',
      expanded: true,
    },
  ];
```

and then use it as the `expanded` property value:

```
<nb-accordion>
    <nb-accordion-item *ngFor="let list of lists" [expanded]="list.expanded">
        <nb-accordion-item-header>
            {{list.name}}
        </nb-accordion-item-header>
        <nb-accordion-item-body >
            Hello
            World
        </nb-accordion-item-body>
    </nb-accordion-item>
</nb-accordion>
```

Here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-e99ybz?file=src/app/home/home.component.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/accordion/overview#nbaccordionitemcomponent), U can use like that =>

HTML

```
<nb-accordion *ngFor="let level of datalist" multi>
   <nb-accordion-item #item>
       <nb-accordion-item-header>header</nb-accordion-item-header>
       <nb-accordion-item-body>body</nb-accordion-item-body>
   </nb-accordion-item>
</nb-accordion>
```

Component

```
@ViewChildren('item') accordion;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {    
   
      this.accordion.changes.subscribe(ac =>
        {
          ac.toArray().forEach(el => {     
              el.toggle();
              this.cdr.detectChanges();
            }); 
        });
        
  }
```

Explanation

1. I used `@ViewChildren` for multiple DOM.
2. And call this DOM Child at `ngAfterViewInit` and just call `toggle(`)

Note: After that u need to call `detectChanges()` method because its can't detect change by automatically.if u don't add this line, u will have this error=>

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'collapsed': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use collapsedChange event

```
 <nb-accordion-item
    (collapsedChange)="getChildModulesList($event,module._id)"
    
    #item *ngFor="let module of parentModuleList ">
```